# rxjava add items after observable was created

Tags: asynchronous, observable, rx-java, rx-android

I just started using rxjava and I got stuck. Maybe I'm not using rxjava in the right way, but I need to add items to an `Observable` after it was created. So I understand that You can just call `Observable.just("Some", "Items")` and the subscribers will receive them, but what if I have an async task and I need to add some more items at later time when the task is finished? I couldn't find anything like `Observable.addItems("Some", "More", "Items")`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

What you probably need is *Subject* - http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html

It is an object that is both *Observer* and *Observable*, so you can subscribe to it and emit new items. For example :

```
PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject.subscribe(System.out::println);
subject.onNext("Item1");
subject.onNext("Item2");
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for...I ignored this class for some reason when I was reading the docs. Thank you!

Comment: If this isn't working for people in kotlin you need to do:                                    `val subject: PublishSubject<String> = PublishSubject.create<String>()`

Answer (score 2):

It is useful to note that `PublishSubject` does not cache items. For example if the above code was the following, `Item1` would not have been printed since the subject was not yet subscribed.
`PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject.onNext("Item1");
subject.subscribe(System.out::println);
subject.onNext("Item2");`

Use `ReplaySubject` for caching.
It would be helpful to read 
[this](https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%201%20-%20Getting%20Started/2.%20Key%20types.md#publishsubject)